# Specify generic class type in argument matcher

Tags: java, generics, jmock

Consider the following piece of code:

```
final Foo foo = context.mock(Foo.class);

context.checking(new Expectations() {{
    one(foo).someMethod(with(aNonNull(List.class)));
}});
```

I'm trying to suggest that `someMethod` is invoked with a non-null argument of type `List<Bar>`. However, I can't figure out the correct syntax to specify that the list contains objects of type Bar. The following simplistic attempt is not valid code:

```
final Foo foo = context.mock(Foo.class);

context.checking(new Expectations() {{
    one(foo).someMethod(with(aNonNull(List<Bar>.class)));
}});
```

Is there a correct way to do this or am I forced to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to my test method?

*I appreciate this is not strictly a JMock-specific question, but I thought I would tag it as such to attract those people who have possibly encountered this problem in the past.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics informations are erased at runtime [JB]Effective Java SE p.l14.
So you have to check this an other way.

I found this method to check the type of all element of the list :

```
final Foo foo = context.mock(Foo.class);

context.checking(new Expectations() {{
    oneOf(foo).someMethod((List<Object>) with(Every.everyItem(IsInstanceOf.instanceOf(Bar.class))));
}});
```

Comment: This explains the root cause and thus attracts the winnings. I'd appreciate further comments from anyone who has been in this situation, who maybe has a different way of approaching the issue.

Comment: Maybe you could write your own Hamcrest matcher - pass in a List.Class and Bar.class and do the matching your self

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to at least centralise the suppression of the warning. For example, you can subclass `Expectations`:

```java
public static class UncheckedExpectations extends Expectations {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T, U extends T> U withUnchecked(Matcher<T> matcher) {
        return (U) super.with(matcher);
    }
}
```

And then use the extra methods:

```java
context.checking(new UncheckedExpectations() {{
    one(foo).someMethod(withUnchecked(aNonNull(List.class)));
}});
```

This is still abuse of generics, because it's using a generic type parameter on a method which is not actually used in the parameters and is only used in the method on an unsafe cast. However, it does at least dodge the issue in a way which doesn't require the same suppression annotation to be scattered all throughout the code.

Hamcrest of course could have made their `with()` method work like this too. It's a bit of a shame that they didn't, because unchecked warnings on Hamcrest code are very common in any codebase using the library.